# Button Styling is not working in any way in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

It seems my class is not working in my JS code. I have attempted a few ways so I'll show you what I have done.

```
 <h2 id="firstbutton" class="firstbutton" type="button">Let's go!</h2>
```

This method let me style, but a button was definitely not visible.

My other way was replacing this with a "button" tag, but this did not let me style the button although I used the class.

```
<button id="firstbutton" class="firstbutton"> Let's go!</button>.
```

This way actually gives me a button, but it was tiny and was not very helpful. Remember in my CSS code I used both of the two methods:

```
.firstbutton {text-align: center;}
```

And my second one:

```
#firstbutton {text-align: center;}
```

I hope I gave enough information as reference and this question does not closed. I am trying to think of another way.... renaming perhaps?

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is generally correct, cut there are several things you need to consider.

1. If the parent tag of your `<h2>` is `<body>` tag, then this `.firstbutton {text-align: center;}` code will work.
2. But if the parent tag of your `<h2>` is not `<body>` tag, you have to align the parent to the center. Example:
   if the parent code is `<div>`, like this:

```
<div>
  <h2 class="firstbutton" type="button">Let's go!</h2>
  <button class="firstbutton">Let's go!</button>
</div>
```

you have to make it like this:

```
<div align="center">
  <h2 class="firstbutton" type="button">Let's go!</h2>
  <button class="firstbutton">Let's go!</button>
</div>
```

Or if you want to use CSS, you can read [this great article](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp).

Let me know if this helpful

Comment: Your example was very helpful in terms of aligning my button but I cannot add other features like font-size, color, font-family, padding and margin etc.  It would be great if you knew how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a button in two ways: using `<input type="button" value="Content!">` and `<button>Content!</button>`.

Styling the buttons using classes and ids as you are doing works as normal.

However, if you are trying to center-align the button, you have to put the styling on the parent element, like so:

```css
.parent {
  text-align: center;
}

input, button {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <input type="button" value="Content!">
  <button>Content!</button>
</div>
```